# DXL: how to get ModName_ of a module using its path

Tags: ibm-doors

I have path of a module. I know how to open (edit/read) it to get a module.

But I don't want to open it because I don't want to use information in it (or because it can't be open), what I want is only to use some function like "getparentfolder".

So I need to be able to retrieve "ModName_" of the module from its path that is a string.

maybe for this particular subject (getparentfolder) there is another method but what I would like is to be able to get ModeName_ from a path.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ModName_ mod = module "full path here"
```

Comment: thanks a lot, easy in fact :) sorry for the dummy question